# Google search console reports indexing my pages with pagination parameters even though they redirect

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, wordpress, google-index, pagination

I recently saw in search console that Google is indexing some of my WordPress posts with pagination.   For example `example.com/post/page/2`. The coverage report says "indexed but not submitted."   It isn't just one URL, but a couple of them.

My posts are not paginated. If you enter the above URL, it automatically redirects to `example.com/post`. Pages 2+ don't exist in actual sense.

How do stop this?

Comment: I found a url like that in Google search console - coverage - indexed but not submitted, and it wasn't just one I found but a couple of them.  In some cases the original post was not indexed and in some cases the original post was indexed. The page/2+ always failed breadcrumbs validation test. The url mydomain.com/post/page/2 gets automatically redirected  mydomain.com/post, when look up on a browser. I hope this reply explains my question and please if you need me to explain further let me know

Comment: Could you do a live test on one of the pagination URLs. e.g. Google Search Console->URL Inspection Live Test. And tell us (or screen share) the response.

Comment: This is what i got when i did the url inspection live test https://imgur.com/VMsqlvL

Comment: That implies Google is not seeing the redirect. To double check I think you can see header information if you click on view crawled page. That should tell you if the page is directly returning a 200 code for Google.